# Thick black edge/border around a React Native app on Android

Tags: android, react-native

Some time back I put together an Android app with React Native. We tested it on a number of devices and haven't had any issues of the sort I'm asking about here.

What I'm asking for here is suggestions about what might be causing this. I'm the developer of the app, but in this case I don't know where to begin.

Recently, someone installed it on an HTC One m7, and there's now this thick black border all the way around the screen where the app should be. There's an image at the end.

You can see the app is still extending the full size it should, but that the edges are blacked out.

This is the first time I've seen this, and after some searching can't seem to find anyone else complaining about this sort of thing. This is the only time I've seen it on any of the devices we've run this on.

Any ideas what might be the cause?

[image]

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I'm experiencing [a problem on tablets which looks similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893805/android-app-showing-black-borders-overlapping-the-edges-of-ui-some-kind-of-com). Have you looked at your app in android studio's layout inspector (tools -> android -> layout inspector)? Does the black border show up there?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion. I haven't but I will. Did yours show up there as well?

Comment: No, for me the black border didn't show in the layout inspector, it just showed the UI as it was meant to be, which makes me think it's not actually part of my activity's view, but something extra android is overlaying on top.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Very helpful. It certainly looks like its something placed on top in my case as well. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @Yhilan did you find a solution to this problem? It works on some of my devices but gives me the same black border on the Nexus 6P (device and emulator). I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @dwhite I did not, unfortunately. I don't possess the phone in the photo, and it's not like that on my own devices, so I've not been able to do much about it. I keep hoping someone will come along with a solution, though.

Comment: Now I have. @danielfeelfine's answer worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I just remove this line:

`<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen_bitmap</item>`

On *res/values/styles.xml*:

And it works fine.

Comment: Dude. You wrote this months ago and I upvoted it at the time but didn't have a chance to try it until now when, on an entirely different app and phone, it happened again. I remembered you'd responded, came back here, tried it, and it worked. Legend. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen_bitmap</item>` solve the issue but you will lost the splash screen. To get the splash screen with `background` to fill the screen add the `bitmap` item as follow.

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>
</item>
```

Comment: for me I need to correctly put images inside resolution folders i.e. xxhdpi, and use `android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

If you still experience this issue after trying all solutions above.

Try the following:

**1. Restart and invalidate caches**

**2. Uninstall the app and reinstall**

Number 2 worked for me.
It seem to be an issue when building the apk, especially when you add and remove some dependencies.