# Android app showing black borders overlapping the edges of UI - some kind of compatibility mode?

Tags: android, user-interface, tablet

I've encountered a strange problem with an android app designed for phones when run on a tablet. The UI is scaled correctly to the device, but there's this big black border overlapping the edges, as if it's trying to show some sort of phone-sized version of the screen.

[image: Layout in a tablet emulator]

Oddly, when using Android Studio's Layout Inspector to try and see what the black border is, it only shows the UI we want to have, with no sign of the black border:

[image: Layout inspector]

I've fiddled with a bunch of settings and tried googling for the issue in every way I can imagine, but can't find anyone with a solution to the issue. Has anyone encountered this or does anyone have an idea of how to fix it?

Comment: can u plz mark in "image" with border you are talking about

Comment: @VishalPatel I mean the area I've highlighted [in this image](http://i.imgur.com/c33wF0w.png)

Comment: @Niall, did you find a solution to this? My app works fine on some phones but gets the black border on the Nexus 6P (device and emulator).

Comment: Also just chiming in to say I have [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484657/thick-black-edge-border-around-a-react-native-app-on-android) and have yet to find a solution.

Comment: I have the same issue an updated the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484657/thick-black-edge-border-around-a-react-native-app-on-android/53907444#53907444

Comment: @FilipeAndrade thanks. I no longer work for the company that made that app, but I'll pass that on to someone who does to see if it works for them.